# sshfs mount to loopback interface which survives disconnects

Tags: linux, ssh, mount

I have a setup in which I use sshfs through the loopback interface to export a folder on another user's home to my home¹.  I mount it using the command

```
sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3
```

The loopback interface drops when the laptop suspends; this causes the sshfs connection to drop as well.  Is there any other option that I may try to use? (I know about autofs, but it seems to me that what I want should be possible to do with sshfs alone)

—

¹ This is used to isolate the dropbox daemon to a user without access to my X session, but it is irrelevant for this question

Comment: How to isolate the dropbox daemon to a user without access to my X session without such a contraption? I have no idea but it *may* be the right question. Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: Possibly I can find another solution for the dropbox daemon, but still I'd like to understand why sshfs on a loopback fails to reconnect, if it should.  And if it should not, why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It drops for the same reason that a regular SSH connection over the loopback interface will do exactly the same thing, all the socket timeouts have expired in the kernel (because the system clock jumps forwards when you suspend and then resume), so both sides just hang up.  SSHFS itself has no code to try and reconnect if the connection *really* drops (and this is such a case).

As far as other options, check out [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/), it should be able to achieve the same result without needing to use the loopback interface, and thus not only sidestep this issue, but also be significantly more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now.  I guess one would have to use autossh, then, to keep connections alive on a laptop.

Comment: bindfs actually does the trick for me with the --map option. That was quite an interesting solution. Thanks a lot @Austin Hemmelgarn